# How to sort the xml having relationship between them using XSLT in a way that the related lines appear below the parent line?

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have this XML :

```
<Details>
    <tag1/>
    <tagn/>
    <Books>
        <Book id = "B1" >
            <ParentRelationships>
                <Relation ParentId = "B4"/>
            </ParentRelationships>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book>
        <Book id = "B5">
            <ParentRelationships>
                <Relation ParentId = "B4"/>
            </ParentRelationships>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book>
        <Book id = "B2">
            <ParentRelationships/>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book>
        <Book id = "B8">
            <ParentRelationships/>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book>
        <Book id = "B4">
            <ParentRelationships/>  
            <ChildRelationships>
                <Relation ChildId = "B1"/>
                <Relation ChildId = "B5"/>
            </ChildRelationships>
        </Book>
    </Books>
</Details>
```

I want to transform it to this sorted using their Id in such a way that the related lines appear below their parent lines in sorted order :

```
<Details>
    <tag1/>
    <tagn/>
    <Books>
        <Book id = "B2">
            <ParentRelationships/>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book>
        <Book id = "B4">
            <ParentRelationships/>  
            <ChildRelationships>
                <Relation ChildId = "B1"/>
                <Relation ChildId = "B5"/>
            </ChildRelationships>
        </Book>
        <Book id = "B1">
            <ParentRelationships>
                <Relation ParentId = "B4"/>
            </ParentRelationships>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book>
        <Book id = "B5" >
            <ParentRelationships>
                <Relation ParentId = "B4"/>
            </ParentRelationships>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book>
        <Book id = "B8">
            <ParentRelationships/>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book> 
    </Books>
</Details>
```

I am new to XSLT and by using XSL sort I am able to sort it normally using :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    

    <xsl:template match="Details/Books">
        <ShipmentLines>
            <xsl:for-each select="Book">
                <xsl:sort select="@id"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </ShipmentLines>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and got output as :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Details>
    <tag1/>
    <tagn/>
    <ShipmentLines><Book id="B1">
            <ParentRelationships>
                <Relation ParentId="B4"/>
            </ParentRelationships>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book><Book id="B2">
            <ParentRelationships/>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book><Book id="B4">
            <ParentRelationships/>  
            <ChildRelationships>
                <Relation ChildId="B1"/>
                <Relation ChildId="B5"/>
            </ChildRelationships>
        </Book><Book id="B5">
            <ParentRelationships>
                <Relation ParentId="B4"/>
            </ParentRelationships>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book><Book id="B8">
            <ParentRelationships/>  
            <ChildRelationships/>
        </Book></ShipmentLines>
</Details>
```

but not able to get the desired output.

Comment: What do you mean with "I am able to sort it but not able to get the desired output"? What did you code? Which (wrong) output did you get? Please edit your question in order to add these missing elements and more people will be able to help you.

Comment: HI @PierreFrançois, thanks for the feedback.
Added the missing details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to place children after their parent:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="Book" use="ParentRelationships/Relation/@ParentId" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Books">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Book[not(ParentRelationships/Relation)]">
            <xsl:sort select="@id"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>  
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Book">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', @id)">
        <xsl:sort select="@id"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to sort instead of using a key, thy this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Books">
    <Books>
      <xsl:for-each 
        select="Book[not(ParentRelationships/Relation/@ParentId)]">
        <xsl:sort select="@id"/>

        <xsl:variable name="ParentId" select="@id"/>

        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>

        <xsl:for-each 
          select="../Book[ParentRelationships/Relation/@ParentId = $ParentId]">
          <xsl:sort select="@id"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </Books>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will give you the desired output.

Comment: This is the same as using a key, only less efficient.

Comment: I fully agree with you. Your code seems even to be more elegant, but I still do not understand it fully. My limitation, sorry...

Comment: On second thought, it's NOT the same thing at all. Not because of the key vs. predicate difference, but rather because my code is recursive: if there is a grandchild, it will be placed after its parent child - while your code will discard it from the output. I guess that's also what you refer to as "elegant".

Comment: Both of the solutions are working for me as in my code, I'll have only parent-child relationship. Thanks for the solutions I was able to get the second approach but could you please shed some light on the first one @michael.hor257k.

Comment: Not sure what exactly is not clear: it starts by applying templates to nodes with no parent; then each node copies itself and continues the process with its children.